# Angular material select add item to observable

Tags: angular

I have material drop-down, where options are bind to an observable `categories`.

```
<mat-select [formControl]="selectForm">
  <mat-option [value]="test">{{test.displayName}}</mat-option>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let item of categories | async" [value]="item">{{item.displayName}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Instead of define an extra option with item `test`, I want to add `test` to my observable? What I tried:

```
export class MyComponent {
  categories: Observable<ICategory[]>;
  test = initialCategory;
  selectForm: FormControl = new FormControl(); 
    
    constructor( private dbService: DbConnector ) { 
      this.categories = this.dbService.readCollection("categories");
    }
    ngOnInit(){
      this.categories.pipe(tap(list => { list.unshift(this.test);}));       
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is almost correct. The problem is that the line you wrote in the `ngOnInit` method is not being assigned.

Try the following:

`constructor(private dbService: DbConnector) { this.categories = this.dbService.readCollection("categories").pipe(map((entries) => [...entries, this.test]) ); }`

Comment: "The problem is ... not being assigned." I thought the observable is assigned in the constructor via ` this.categories = this.dbService.readCollection("categories");`. And inside `ngOnInit` I update the observable by pushing an object into the observable. Why to re-assign the observable?

Comment: It's not the way you update and observable. You cannot "push" new values inside an observable. You can do that on an instance of `BehaviorSubject` or `Subject`. The line you wrote into ngOnInit, essentially does not nothing. You are creating a derivated observable on which you are subscribing nowhere, so your logic into the tap operator won't be executed.